How to solve the error in the Flutter basic library
I don't know why this error is coming up. I also did:
import 'package: flutter/material.dart'.

The default library is undefined
Error Screen

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you imported the material package correctly?
it's suspected that you are giving a white space before flutter word in package import.
import it like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Hope it helps you.

First, try to reload VS Code or other editor you use.
Second, on the popup window you shown there is a second link Quick Fix... Click on it end execute suffested fix.
